# Mapping between node spaces

Tags: kineticjs

I am new to Kineticjs. I have used Piccolo2d and currently I am using cocos2dx. When I am working with nodes I can map from a node's coordinate space into another node's coordinate space. For example, mapping from local to world to view space.

I searched through Kineticjs' documents looking for similar functionality. I thought Node, Layer, Transform or Container classes would have transforms for this but I don't seem to see it. Perhaps I am looking in the wrong area.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 functions to retrieve any node's position:

1. `getPosition()` to get position relative to parent, [refer](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#getPosition)
2. `getAbsolutePosition()` to get position relative to stage, [refer](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Node.html#getAbsolutePosition)

Similarly, there are 2 functions to retrieve any node's transform:

1. `getTransform()` to get position relative to parent, [refer](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#getTransform)
2. `getAbsoluteTransform()` to get position relative to stage, [refer](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Node.html#getAbsoluteTransform)

Comment: Interesting. I will have to look at those and see how they can be used to map from one node to another. It appears that from the functions you mentioned I would need to use these to build a mapping transform from space to space.

Comment: I'm not sure what your view-space is. The concept is generally used in 3d terms, whereas local to world is taken care using the functions I mentioned above. Also, you can use `MoveTo()` for moving a node from one container to other. Here is the link: http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Node.html#moveTo

Comment: Ultimately I want to be able "snap" a node in one layer to another node in another layer. For example, one could be a "handle" to a polygon path and I want to snap it to another polygon's handle that is in another layer. So I really don't want to "move" a node from layer to layer but really reference the space of another layer for snapping--if any of that makes sense. However, thanks for the MoveTo() tip.